# Sync Tables from MySQL to MSSSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, synchronization

Is there a way to sync specific tables from MySQL to MSSQL and vice versa?

For example:

-Sync tbl_employees(MySQL) to tbl_employees(MSSQL)
-Sync tbl_attendance(MSSQL) to tbl_attendance(MySQL)

I've read about MSSQL Linked Server, but I don't really understand how it works.

What I want is that whenever there are changes on the MySQL database when I use PHP, the changes will be synced automatically to MSSQL database which is manipulated by a .NET application.

I don't know if I explained it well enough. If you have any questions, please ask on the comments. It would really help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set-up SQL Server Linked Server to MySQL, 
then synchronize the tables what ever u want

more details are here???

http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/

Comment: So I've created a linked server to MySQL. Now how do I sync tables from MySQL to MSSQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create a middle layer application with multiple connection... and do it manually...but its only applicable for small scale purposes.else
You can Create a linked server between SQLServer and MySQL Server. configure the Linked Server Provider, but all subsequent connections require only a DSN and Linked Server.